# Shared library progress/status messages

Tags: c#, architecture, software-design

I have a method that does some stuff that takes a while and posts progress/status messages back. The method used to be the `Main()` static method in my console `Program` class. Later, I decided to move the functionality into a shared library assembly, so that the same functionality could be accessed by a new web api project, so a different user interface with different mechanisms for stdio.

What is a good design pattern to replace all my `Console.Writeline()` calls in the moved method?

I'm thinking along the lines of adding an observable collection (of strings) to store the messages and then getting any calling assemblies to subscribe to changes on the collection and implement their own ui mechanisms for displaying messages back to the user.

Is this reasonable or is this reinventing the wheel? Is there already a purpose built method in the framework to handle a scenario like this?

Edit:

Thanks to @astef, I implemented it like so:

```
public interface IMessageObserver
{
    void Notify(string message);
    void Notify(string format, params object[] args);
}

public class ConsoleMessageObserver : IMessageObserver
{
    public void Notify(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public void Notify(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(format, args);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Library.LongRunningMethod(new ConsoleMessageObserver());
    }
}

static class Library
{
    public static void LongRunningMethod(IMessageObserver observer)
    {
        observer.Notify("Some progress happened...");
    }
}
```

Comment: How about adding an event?  That way the main program (or logging client) can subscribe to the event and format, display or log the status events as it requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need someone to handle your progress messages, just define it:

```
public interface IProgressObserver
{
    void NotifyProgress(double done);
}
```

And use:

```
public void YourLongRunningMethod(IProgressObserver progressObserver)
{
    // ...

    progressObserver.NotifyProgress(1d);
}
```

Now you can be more specific on who will actually handle this messages. For example:

```
public class ConsoleProgressObserver : IProgressObserver
{
    public void NotifyProgress(double done)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Progress: {0:0.00}%", done * 100);
    }
}
```

Here's one that was used in Windows 98 system ;)

```
public class StuckingProgressObserver : IProgressObserver
{
    private const double stucksAfter = 0.95;

    private readonly IProgressObserver wrapee;

    public StuckingProgressObserver(IProgressObserver wrapee)
    {
        this.wrapee = wrapee;
    }

    public void NotifyProgress(double done)
    {
        if (done < stucksAfter)
        {
            wrapee.NotifyProgress(done);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's very elegant and works well. Thanks! I modified it slightly since I am interested in message strings rather than percent completion, but its a very simple and effective pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Using an event, like @astef suggests is a good idea, but their code isn't idiomatic C#. .NET supports delegates directly, so there is no need for a one method interface.

In C# we'd define a `class ProgressChangedEventArgs : EventArgs` and then add an `EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged` to the class that generates the event.

In fact the framework already includes those in the `System.ComponentModel` namespace.

Comment: I liked @astef's solution mostly because it _isn't_ event based. The one method interface actually seemed rather elegant (to me) since it exposes only the functionality I want (replacing `Console.Writeline()` with `observer.Notify()`) and allows me to implement the UI messaging in any appropriate way. I wish `Console` was already an implementation of some UI interaction interface which would have eliminated the need for my own interface.

Comment: @grenade I think that the library sending the progress in form of message strings is the wrong abstraction level. In most situations, the library should raise events that the calling application *understands*, not strings the application merely passes through.